# How to get the position of the object without touching it in react naitve?

Tags: react-native, slider, drag-event

I want to get the position of the object without touching the view or the object.
I am using [enter link description here](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-slider)

to slide the object but i want to get the position of the object without touching the slider.
Is there any way to get the position.

Comment: Your description is not clear. You attached link to slider package but better would be screenshot with pointed object you want. Anyway to get position you can use measureLayout https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurelayoutrelativetonativecomponentref-onsuccess-onfail

Comment: @CodeJoe Thanks for the suggestion i got the position of the object with the help of the measureLayout props.

Comment: I'm happy to hear it :) I'll convert it to answer so other users could easily find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the position of element you can use measureLayout.
It's well explained with provided example in documentation:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurelayoutrelativetonativecomponentref-onsuccess-onfail